# dynamic content in sidebar in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, sidebar

I'm trying to create a map with [sidebar plugin](https://github.com/turbo87/leaflet-sidebar/). I can make a map with many markers and plugin from "demo example", but I don't know, how to create a "dynamic" content in slidebar which shows atributes from each marker separately.

My simple code:

```
<script>
var map = L.map('map');

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; OpenStreetMap contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var sidebar = L.control.sidebar('sidebar', {
    closeButton: true,
    position: 'left'
});
map.addControl(sidebar);
sidebar.setContent('aaaaaaa');   

setTimeout(function () {
    sidebar.show();
}, 500);
var marker = L.marker([49.46, 17.11]).addTo(map).on('click', function () {
    sidebar.toogle()
    marker.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.").openPopup();
sidebar.setContent('aaaaaaa');   

    map.on('click', function () {
        sidebar.hide();
    });
});

map.setView([49, 17], 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the content manually, and update the sidebar every time the data changes, check [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/yt9Lxme1/).

First, create a function to update your data, you can use `map.eacheLayer` to get all the layers, something like this:

```
function updateDataInSidebar() {
    var newData = '<div id="layer-data">';
    map.eachLayer(function (layer) { 
        if (layer.options.id) {
            newData += 'Marker' + layer.options.id + '<br />'; 
        }
    });
    sidebar.setContent(newData + '</div>')
}
```

You can store arbitrary data in options, like this:

```
marker = createMarker(lat, lng);
marker.options.id = '123';
```

You can use the data stored in the options to populate your sidebar, to get the current position of your marker, user `getLatLng`;

Comment: It look better to understand, but can you add the function "updateDataInSidebar" into the example with two markers please ? Because Im a little lama :-) Thanks

Comment: The function takes all markers in the map, check the link and see that in my example it show two markers in the sidebar.

Comment: @JakubKohn another option is to store all markers in a array, and use that array in your update function.